# NodeJS response.send() crashes with large string

Tags: node.js, express

Quite simply my Node server crashes with heap out of memory (string too large).

I am trying to return a very large data sent from Mongoose.

```
 response.send({success: true, message: "Data Report Generated", result: <very very large array>})
```

I already have my node server allocated with 14GB of memory using --max_old_space_size=14000 flag on my node command and adding more memory is not what I want to do.

I am out of options and need a solution.

Comment: 1)  Can you break up the data in any way?  Such as multiple requests?
2)  Or can you use Stream:  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html to buffer the data for you?

Comment: ideally no because i need that data whole so i can export it to a .csv file and manipulation on the angular front end.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possibilities for addressing this issue.  You provide us with no specifics at all about the data or the application so all we can do is offer generic suggestions:

1. Collect the data in smaller pieces and stream it to the client rather than accumulating it all into memory at once and then trying to `JSON.stringify()` a massive array all at once.  That will end up with multiple copies of the data in memory at once as each layer works at sending it.
2. Use built-in database support for streamed responses.
3. Examine how the data is constructed and change the format to massively reduce the size of the stringified JSON.  For example, a giant array of objects where each object has multiple properties will repeat the property names over and over and over for every single object.  There are much more space efficient ways to transfer that data (that aren't plain JSON such as comma delimited lists).
4. Make sure you have gzip compression enabled (though your problem is probably before that would help you).
5. Have the client request the data in chunks with several requests.
6. Rethink how the client works so you don't have to transfer massive amounts of data to the client at once.  For example, the client could be more demand driven and request data as needed with ajax calls rather than fetching all the data at once.  Large virtual tables can be constructed this way where more data is fetched as the user scrolls.
7. Find ways to trim things out of the data being sent to the client.
8. Use shorter names in your repeated JSON property names.

If you showed a segment of the data you're sending and explained the overall application that wants to send this much data to the client, we could perhaps help with ways to change the design so you don't have to send as much data all at once or suggest more efficient ways to send it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading all data from mongoose at once, you can use the [QueryStream](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/querystream.html) to fetch the data as a read stream and pipe the stream to response, once all data read, call response.end to fullfill the request

```js
const queryStream = Model.find().stream();
queryStream.pipe(response);
queryStream.on('end', () => response.end());
```

on client side, send the ajax call as usual, it will be resolved once all data streamed

```js
this.http.get('http://api_endpoint')
  .subscribe((data) => {
    // ...    
  });
```

Comment: This is interesting but how would my frontend interpret and wait for it all ?  I am using angular 7 for my front end part.

Comment: hi @kjohnsonthecoder please see the updated answer.